# LINQ syntax across Many-to-Many

Tags: linq, entity-framework, many-to-many

I've been struggling with LINQ a bit, and was after help.  I could do it in SQL, but can't seem to work out how to in LINQ.
I have a SQL Compact 4.0 Database, with a Entity Framework 4.0 EDMX modelling it, in C#.

This is the scenario, these tables:
    Customers - OrderDetails - Orders

The OrderDetails table is a non-payload table, just facilitating the many to many join.

If I'm given an CustomerId Number as a parameter, I want to return an `IEnumerable<Orders>`.

In SQL I would've written this as:

```
SELECT     Orders.*  
FROM         OrderDetails INNER JOIN  
                  Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderId = Orders.OrderId INNER JOIN  
                  Customers ON OrderDetails.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId
```

How can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: How many Entities your model has ??

Comment: Just realised that I've confused myself with replacing my tables with the ol' Northwind equivalents (to keep some anonymity).  As lets face it, how often would an order have many customers!  Sorry.

But essentially the non-payload middle table is hidden on the display of the EDMX.

Comment: Would this work?     return db.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == id).Customers;

Comment: @DavidC: I thought the idea is to return orders, not customers. The SQL is somewhat confused, admittedly.

Comment: @Jon Skeet  I wish I could go back and edit the question when I had realised it was a little confusing, but that would make the replies look out of sorts, which is unfair.  But yes it is meant to be the Orders that I am returning (I've got confused when replacing with Northwind style, sorry).  So return db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Customer == id).Orders

Comment: @DavidC: Potentially... I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "think in SQL", you can do this as a query expression like this:

```
int customerId = ...;
var query = from detail in OrderDetails
            where detail.CustomerId == customerId
            join order in Orders on detail.OrderId equals order.OrderId
            select order;
```

Note that this doesn't actually touch the Customers table at all... I'm assuming that there are enough relational constraints to ensure that `OrderDetails.CustomerId` really does refer to a real customer.

If you have all the relationships set up appropriately, however, you can use something like Sjoerd's answer. Note that that will first fetch the `Customer` entity, whereas the above query doesn't. It's a more OO way of thinking about things though.

EDIT: As it appears your relationships are set up appropriately, two options:

```
// This will involve checking the customer data first
var customer = db.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == customerId);
if (customer != null)
{
    var orders = customer.Orders;
}

// This shouldn't... hopefully :) You'll end up with an empty sequence if
// the customer doesn't exist
var orders = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId)
                         .SelectMany(c => c.Orders);
```

Comment: I appreciate the angle you have taken with this given that I am more familiar with SQL.  But as you also mention, as best I know all the relationships are set up correctly in the Model.

Comment: @DavidC: In which case using the relationships should be fine. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Customer customer = DataContext.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == CustomerId);
IEnumberable<Order> orders = customer.OrderDetails.Orders;
```

Comment: There is no OrderDetails Entity
In many to many relation the mid table not represented as an entity

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work :

```
int customerId = ...;
var query = Customers.Include("Orders").Where(cust => cust.CustomerID == customerId)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all orders which have at least one customer with ID `customerId` you could also try this:

```
var orders = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Customers.Any(c => c.CustomerId == customerId)).ToList();
```

It looks somewhat weird to me that one order can have many customers but that's how I understand your description: "Customers - OrderDetails - Orders ... The OrderDetails table is a non-payload table, just facilitating the many to many join."

I'm expecting that an `Order` in your EntityModel has a navigation collection of `Customers` and `OrderDetails` is only a internal join table not existing as an entity.